# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. This error is shown in shutil.move()

Tags: python, shutil, try-except, file-organization, permissionerror

shutil.move() function doesn't seem to work properly in the following code and is showing the attached error.

*Error*: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

```
if file.is_file():
    # print(file.suffix.lower()
    if file.suffix.lower() in extension_paths:
        destination_path = destination_dir / extension_paths[file.suffix.lower()]
    else:
        destination_path = destination_dir / extension_paths['noname']
    destination_path = add_date_to_file(destination_path)
    destination_path = rename_file(file, destination_path)
    shutil.move(str(file), str(destination_path))
```

I have been trying to debug this code a lot lately.
I found that if I use the below code, the code works fine except both the 'try' and 'except' blocks run. Is that possible? If so, how?

```
try:
    if file.suffix.lower() in extension_paths:
        destination_path = destination_dir / extension_paths[file.suffix.lower()]
    else:
        destination_path = destination_dir / extension_paths['noname']
    destination_path = add_date_to_file(destination_path)
    destination_path = rename_file(file, destination_path)
    shutil.move(str(file), str(destination_path))
except (Exception,):
    pass
```

I would be grateful if somebody comes up with the reason of the error. Thanks!

Comment: that's because your file is locked by either your program (open without close) or another program. python is not at fault here

Comment: this is a common occurrence in windows, which locks open files, with the logic being that they cannot be written to simultaneously. So ensure that the file is closed first.

Comment: @D.L
I am very much new to python, I read quite a handful of documents in this regard. Can you suggest me how to close a file or at least how to check if a file is closed or not using pathlib module? Thanks.

Comment: checking for this depends of the type of file that you are trying to read.

Comment: also, i believe that some applications, like excel, are blocking. whilst others are not, so the question will have to be more specific.